# WildFly Messaging Configuration For Message Retry Control

Tags: wildfly, activemq-artemis

We are running WildFly 26 in a cluster and observe the automatic retry of JMS message when exception is thrown. All is working as expected where the message retries multiple times with a small delay between attempts.

However, we would like to limit the # retries instead of using the default which appears to be 10. The only place I have seen that allows you to set max-retries is in the JMS Bridge. The discussion and examples for JMS Bridge is for connecting to an external JMS subsystem. How do I configure WildFly to limit the number of retries ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `max-delivery-attempts` in an `address-setting` with an appropriate `name` value, e.g.:

```xml
<address-setting name="jms.queue.MyQueue" max-delivery-attempts="10"/>
```

If you want this to apply to *all* addresses then use `name="#"`. The default `standalone-full.xml` already has such an `address-setting` which you can modify.